# Writing to SQLite dataset when other processes are reading from it

Tags: concurrency, sqlite

Reading the SQLite documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html), when a process wants to write to a SQLite database it obtains a reserved lock.  Then once the process is ready to write to disk it obtains a pending lock, during which no new processes can obtain a shared lock, but existing shared locks are allowed to finish their business.  Once the remaining shared locks clear, the process can write.

However...when I try to write a database while other processes are reading from that database, I just get an immediate "Error: dataset is locked".

```
sqlite> insert into meta_models (model) values ("hello_world");
Error: database is locked
```

Why doesn't SQLite it go through the steps I outlined above of waiting for the shared locks to clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does go through these steps, but it timed out while waiting for the remaining shared locks to clear.

You can adjust this timeout with [PRAGMA busy_timeout](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout).